# Dealing with circular dependency on inheritance

Tags: c++, class, architecture, circular-dependency

I'm gonna go C++ über n00b on this one and ask how is the best way to deal with a circular dependency when you have inheritance.

The set is simple: Scene class extends Actor; Scene has a pointer to a vector of Actors; Actor has a pointer for (parent) Scene.

As for include files I got:

Scene.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#ifndef __Scene_h__
#define __Scene_h__

#include "Actor.h"

namespace myns
{
    // class Actor;
    class Scene;
}

namespace myns
{
    class Scene: public myns::Actor
    {
        /* private class attributes... */

        public:
            /* public class attributes... */

            std::vector<myns::Actor*> actors;

            Scene(/* arguments */);

            /* public class methods... */
    };
}

#endif
```

Actor.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#ifndef __Actor_h__
#define __Actor_h__

#include "Scene.h"

namespace myns
{
    // class Scene;
    class Actor;
}

namespace myns
{
    class Actor
    {
        /* private class attributes... */

        public:
            /* public class attributes... */

            myns::Scene* scene;

            Actor();

            Actor(/* arguments */);

            /* public class methods... */
    };
}

#endif
```

But this gives me alot of C2504 errors/base class undefined on Visual Studio 2010.

If I comment the Scene.h include on the Actor.h and uncomment the forward declaration of Scene on Actor.h it works, but then, in my app, if I want to include only the Actor.h on a particular piece of code, it will not work. How can I put this to work while maintaining the inclusion independence for Actor.h - including Actor.h without the need of previously manually including Scene.h?

What is wrong with my class definitions and how is the best way to deal with this circular dependency?

Shouldn't the #ifndef directives prevent this inclusion problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but then, in my app, if I want to include only the Actor.h on a particular piece of code, it will not work

What you need to do is in the .cpp file where you need to <del>use</del> define the `Actor` class you must `include` both Actor.h *and* Scene.h. That way the forward declaration will be resolved and everything should work.

As an aside, you should move your `#ifndef` and `#define` right to the top of the file, before the `include`s. Also, having a `using` in a header file is bad practice because other files that `include` your header might not work properly. It should be ok to put it inside your `namespace myns { ... }` though.

Comment: Is there any way that I could declare my classes so that I could only include Actor.h when I only need an Actor (having the Actor.h take care of it's dependencies)?

Is this dependency delegation standard C++ practice?

And assuming that all these classes are part of a library is it a best practice to make a Library.h that does all these includes in proper order and then on my app only including Libray.h?

Comment: There shouldn't really be any circumstances where you need to include both files to use `Actor` except in Actor.cpp, because otherwise that would mean you use `Scene` in Actor.h, which shouldn't work because you've only got a forward declaration.

Comment: Oh, ok I got that last comment. Yes, it makes sense, well pointed.

Answer (score 1):

Is a Scene really a type of Actor?

If it is, Actors probably shouldn't know about Scenes. Base classes shouldn't usually know about their derived classes.

Where is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here? What action do you perform on an Actor that would be polymorphically performed differently by a Scene.

In any case, Scene derives from Actor so must include its base class. But in Actor.h if you really do need the Scene class it must be a forward declaration only.

In the compilation units (the .cpp files) you might include both headers if required.

Comment: The namespace is a typo. :) Corrected.

Comment: Nope. A Scene extends an actor (I need Actor properties such as representations and behaviours/backstageactions), so it's a special kind of (super) Actor. But again an Actor is placed on a Scene and it needs to comunicate with it (terminate scene, etc.).

I'm gonna check that principle and get back to you.